# Ошибка: Неправильно набран адрес, или такой страницы на сайте больше не существует

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс, компоненты, error404

Помогите, очень нужно. Проблема в том, что при отображении детальной страницы `http://mytechnosite.ru/news/prevoznemogaya-slozhivshuyusya-neprostuyu-ekonomicheskuyu-situatsiyu/` комплексного компонента `news` выдает ошибку:

Неправильно набран адрес,
или такой страницы на сайте больше не существует.
Вернитесь на главную или воспользуйтесь картой сайта.

Есть комплексный компонент `news` на странице http://mytechnosite.ru/news/ в разделе Новости:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с кодом

```html
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Новости для поисковиков");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Публикации");
?>
  <section>
    <div class="gray_bg">
      <div class="standart_width">
        <div class="title">
          <?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle(false);?>
        </div>
        <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news", 
    "page", 
    array(
        "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "N",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "j F Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "DETAIL_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "SHOW_COUNTER",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
        "DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
        "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "FILE_404" => "",
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "6",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "info",
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
        "LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "j F Y",
        "LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
        "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
        "NEWS_COUNT" => "7",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
        "SEF_FOLDER" => "/news/",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
        "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_404" => "Y",
        "SORT_BY1" => "ID",
        "SORT_BY2" => "",
        "SORT_ORDER1" => "ASC",
        "SORT_ORDER2" => "",
        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
        "USE_CATEGORIES" => "N",
        "USE_FILTER" => "N",
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
        "USE_RATING" => "N",
        "USE_REVIEW" => "N",
        "USE_RSS" => "N",
        "USE_SEARCH" => "N",
        "USE_SHARE" => "N",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "page",
        "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
            "news" => "",
            "section" => "",
            "detail" => "/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
        )
    ),
    false
);?>

          <a class="ajax-pager-link more_bt" href="">Показать больше публикаций</a>
          <div class="number_bl">
            <a class="prev" href=""></a>
            <a href="">1</a>
            <a class="active" href="">2</a>
            <a href="">3</a>
            <a href="">4</a>
            <span>...</span>
            <a href="">9</a>
            <a class="next" href=""></a>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

И есть следующий вызов подкомпонента `news.list` компонента `news` на `C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnosite.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news\page\news.php`

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>

<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.list",
    "news_index",
    Array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "NEWS_COUNT" => $arParams["NEWS_COUNT"],
        "SORT_BY1" => $arParams["SORT_BY1"],
        "SORT_ORDER1" => $arParams["SORT_ORDER1"],
        "SORT_BY2" => $arParams["SORT_BY2"],
        "SORT_ORDER2" => $arParams["SORT_ORDER2"],
        "FIELD_CODE" => $arParams["LIST_FIELD_CODE"],
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => $arParams["LIST_PROPERTY_CODE"],
        "DETAIL_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["detail"],
        "SECTION_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["section"],
        "IBLOCK_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["news"],
        "DISPLAY_PANEL" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PANEL"],
        "SET_TITLE" => $arParams["SET_TITLE"],
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => $arParams["SET_LAST_MODIFIED"],
        "MESSAGE_404" => $arParams["MESSAGE_404"],
        "SET_STATUS_404" => $arParams["SET_STATUS_404"],
        "SHOW_404" => $arParams["SHOW_404"],
        "FILE_404" => $arParams["FILE_404"],
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => $arParams["INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN"],
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
        "CACHE_FILTER" => $arParams["CACHE_FILTER"],
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => $arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"],
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => $arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"],
        "PAGER_TITLE" => $arParams["PAGER_TITLE"],
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => $arParams["PAGER_TEMPLATE"],
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => $arParams["PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS"],
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => $arParams["PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING"],
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME"],
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => $arParams["PAGER_SHOW_ALL"],
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => $arParams["PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE"],
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK" => $arParams["PAGER_BASE_LINK"],
        "PAGER_PARAMS_NAME" => $arParams["PAGER_PARAMS_NAME"],
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => $arParams["DISPLAY_DATE"],
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"],
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT"],
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => $arParams["PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN"],
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => $arParams["LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT"],
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => $arParams["USE_PERMISSIONS"],
        "GROUP_PERMISSIONS" => $arParams["GROUP_PERMISSIONS"],
        "FILTER_NAME" => $arParams["FILTER_NAME"],
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => $arParams["HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL"],
        "CHECK_DATES" => $arParams["CHECK_DATES"],
    ),
    $component
);?>
```

Есть также код шаблона `news_index` компонента `news.list`, расположенный на `C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnosite.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news.list\news_index`:

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<div class="news_list">
<?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
    <?
    $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
    $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
    ?>
    <div class="news_el" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
        <div class="news_el_img">
            <a href="<?=$arItem['DETAIL_PAGE_URL']?>" title="<?=$arItem['NAME']?>"><img src="<?=$arItem['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC']?>" alt="<?=$arItem['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['ALT']?>"/></a>
            <div class="news_el_data"><?=$arItem['DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM']?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="news_el_cont">
            <div class="news_el_tit"><a href="<?=$arItem['DETAIL_PAGE_URL']?>"><?=$arItem['NAME']?></a></div>
            <div class="news_el_txt"><?=$arItem['PREVIEW_TEXT']?></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
<?endforeach;?>
</div>
```

Компонент `news` имеет следующие настройки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Инфоблок **Новости** имеет следующую структуру

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Элемент **Превознемогая сложившуюся непростую экономическую ситуацию** инфоблока **Новости** содержит следующую информацию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Несмотря на все вышеперечисленное при щелчке на элементе с подписью **Превознемогая сложившуюся непростую экономическую ситуацию** в 1-ом скриншоте выдает следующее окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добиться отображения информации из элемента **Превознемогая сложившуюся непростую экономическую ситуацию** инфоблока **Новости** на детальной странице инфоблока? Должно выглядеть как на

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Файл `C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnosite.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news\page\detail.php`
имеет следующий вид

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<?$ElementID = $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.detail",
    "",
    Array(
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => $arParams["DISPLAY_DATE"],
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => $arParams["DISPLAY_NAME"],
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"],
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT"],
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "FIELD_CODE" => $arParams["DETAIL_FIELD_CODE"],
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => $arParams["DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE"],
        "DETAIL_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["detail"],
        "SECTION_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["section"],
        "META_KEYWORDS" => $arParams["META_KEYWORDS"],
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => $arParams["META_DESCRIPTION"],
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => $arParams["BROWSER_TITLE"],
        "SET_CANONICAL_URL" => $arParams["DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL"],
        "DISPLAY_PANEL" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PANEL"],
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => $arParams["SET_LAST_MODIFIED"],
        "SET_TITLE" => $arParams["SET_TITLE"],
        "MESSAGE_404" => $arParams["MESSAGE_404"],
        "SET_STATUS_404" => $arParams["SET_STATUS_404"],
        "SHOW_404" => $arParams["SHOW_404"],
        "FILE_404" => $arParams["FILE_404"],
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => $arParams["INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN"],
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => $arParams["ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN"],
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => $arParams["DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT"],
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => $arParams["USE_PERMISSIONS"],
        "GROUP_PERMISSIONS" => $arParams["GROUP_PERMISSIONS"],
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => $arParams["DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"],
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => $arParams["DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"],
        "PAGER_TITLE" => $arParams["DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE"],
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => $arParams["DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE"],
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => $arParams["DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL"],
        "CHECK_DATES" => $arParams["CHECK_DATES"],
        "ELEMENT_ID" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["ELEMENT_ID"],
        "ELEMENT_CODE" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["ELEMENT_CODE"],
        "SECTION_ID" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_ID"],
        "SECTION_CODE" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_CODE"],
        "IBLOCK_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["news"],
        "USE_SHARE" => $arParams["USE_SHARE"],
        "SHARE_HIDE" => $arParams["SHARE_HIDE"],
        "SHARE_TEMPLATE" => $arParams["SHARE_TEMPLATE"],
        "SHARE_HANDLERS" => $arParams["SHARE_HANDLERS"],
        "SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_LOGIN" => $arParams["SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_LOGIN"],
        "SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_KEY" => $arParams["SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_KEY"],
        "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => (isset($arParams["ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN"]) ? $arParams["ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN"] : ''),
        'STRICT_SECTION_CHECK' => (isset($arParams['STRICT_SECTION_CHECK']) ? $arParams['STRICT_SECTION_CHECK'] : ''),
    ),
    $component
);?>
<p><a href="<?=$arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["news"]?>"><?=GetMessage("T_NEWS_DETAIL_BACK")?></a></p>
```

Файл `C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnosite.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news\page\bitrix\news.detail\.default\template.php` имеет вид

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<div class="gray_bg">
    <div class="standart_width">
        <h1><?=$arResult["NAME"]?></h1>
        <div class="clear_after">
            <img align="left" src="<?=$arItem['DETAIL_PICTURE']['SRC']?>" alt=""/>
            <?=$arItem['DETAIL_TEXT']?>
            <div class="news_det_info clear_after">
                <div class="news_det_data"><?=$arItem['DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM']?></div>
                <div class="news_det_look"><?=$arItem['SHOW_COUNTER']?></div>
                <div class="news_det_back"><a href="">Назад к публикациям</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я пытался редактировать эти 2 файла, но все равно при открытии детальной страницы выдает ошибку:

Неправильно набран адрес,
или такой страницы на сайте больше не существует.
Вернитесь на главную или воспользуйтесь картой сайта.

При создании сайта я основывался на следующих видеоуроках - [05. Новости сайта. 03. Комплексный компонент в разделе новости](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9xZZG4alOA&list=PL90VyUHz4BpFhObHt2VVW3tAyUMcJ4kL1&index=19), [05. Новости сайта. 04. Шаблон списка новостей в разделе Новости](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgB0WX_KQh4&list=PL90VyUHz4BpFhObHt2VVW3tAyUMcJ4kL1&index=20), [05. Новости сайта. 05. Шаблон детальной новости в разделе Новости](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6kmiUIQT_4&list=PL90VyUHz4BpFhObHt2VVW3tAyUMcJ4kL1&index=21&t=106s).

Сравнивал с [Как создать страницу новостей на комплексном компоненте в Битрикс с ЧПУ](https://r-morozov.ru/bitrix/kak-sozdat-stranicu-novostej-na-kompleksnom-komponente-v-bitriks-s-chpu/)
 - поменял в настройках ЧПУ компонента и инфоблока с `/#ELEMENT_CODE#/` на `/detail/#ELEMENT_CODE#/` - не помогло, та же ошибка. А в остальном все совпадает.

Comment: Подскажите хотя бы на каком из этапов подключения комплексного компонента news я ошибся или что-то не указал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы разобраться в том, на каком этапе произошла ошибка, необходимо понимать процесс обработки адресов в Битриксе.

Когда Вы открываете какую-то страницу на сайте, запрос проходит примерно следующий путь:

1. Сначала запрос принимает HTTP-сервер
   как правило это Apache HTTP Server или nginx (иногда оба) 
   *(OpenServer, XAMPP, Denver сами не обрабатывают http, они просто имеют в своем составе Apache)*
2. Далее в игру вступают правила обработки адресов, указанные в настройках http-сервера.
3. После чего http сервер передает управление компоненту, отвечающему за интерпретацию php скрипта

   - Для Apache это, как правило, модуль mod_php
   - nginx, как правило, передает управление менеджеру процессов php-fpm (в тех случаях, когда он не перенаправляет запрос в Apache)
4. Далее обработка запроса передается Битриксу, который в свою очередь просматривает поочереди все правила обработки адресов, зарегистрированные в файле `urlrewrite.php` и если он находит соответствие текущего запроса и правила, то он передает управление скрипту, указанному в поле `PATH` и компоненту, указанному в поле `ID`
5. Если данный компонент комплексный и у него имеются настройки ЧПУ
   Как правило в параметрах комплексного компонента имеются шаблоны правил обработки адресов, входящтх в состав дочерних компонентов. Они хранятся в поле `SEF_URL_TEMPLATES`...если их нет, то используются правила обработки адресов данного компонента, указанные по умолчанию в исходниках используемого компонента.

---

## Пройдемся по данной цепочке

1. На свой запрос, вы получаете HTTP ответ с корректным статусом, а это значит, что http сервер сделал свое дело.
2. Относительно правильности правил обработки запросов на стороне HTTP сервера невозможно на 100% точно ответить с имеющимися данными. Тем не менее из них видно, что запросы обрабатываются php и что список новостей выводится нормально.
   Если у Вас Apache HTTP сервер, то вам стоит проверить `.htaccess`
   Для корректной обработки адресов Битрикс рекомендует проставить там следующее правило:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

3. По поводу следующего шага мы можем с уверонностью ответить, что он отработал корректно, поскольку мы видим результаты работы интерпретатора php и работы Битрикса
4. Со следующим шагом все не так однозначно:

   - с одной стороны мы видим список новостей, что может говорить о наличии корректного правила в `urlrewrite.php`
   - с другой стороны, если у Вас в Apache есть настройки индексных страниц, то результат может быть таким же.
     На данном этапе Вы можете проверить наличия правила комплексного компонента новостей в файле `urlrewrite.php`. По сути, все запросы, начинающиеся с `/news/...` должны передаваться данному компоненту и там должно быть что-то такое:

```
array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/news/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/news/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
)
```

5. Далее Вам необходимо проверить шаблоны обработки адресов комплексного компонента новостей
   К счастью тут гадать не нужно, потому что Вы указали их в вопросе:

```
"SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
    "news" => "",
    "section" => "",
    "detail" => "/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
 )
```

И данные настройки меня смущают:
Для детальной сраницы Вы указываете адрес, начинающийся от корня  `/#ELEMENT_CODE#/`...

Попробуйте заменить данное правило на относительное:

```
    "detail" => "#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
```

и тогда Битрикс будет прибавлять в начале пути часть указанную в правиле в `urlrewrite.php`

Либо попробуйте заменить на правило, включающее в себя полный путь вместе с `/news/`

```
    "detail" => "/news/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
```

Comment: Правильно, проблема была в переднем слэше перед `#ELEMENT_CODE#/`.