# Создание карты сайта из собственных инфоблоков и удаление старых. Удаление элементов из админки, ссылающихся на папку news

Tags: windows, веб-программирование, битрикс, настройки, админка

Для ответа на данный вопрос необходимо установить Битрикс в свободную папку и при установке выбрать шаблон Интернет магазин Одежда.

1. В связи с [Ошибка: Неправильно набран адрес, или такой страницы на сайте больше не существует.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1505715/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83)
   , а именно со скриншотом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я понял, что в админке битрикса сохранилась информация шаблона Интернет магазин Одежда, а именно инфоблоков Обувь(7), Пантолеты(1), Тапочки(2), Туфли(4), Платья(4), Штаны(3), Нижнее белье(7), Футболки(5), Спортивная одежда(6), Аксессуары(6), Ремни(6). В админке эти данные находятся в

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из скриншота с ошибкой карта сайта состоит из этих блоков (взятых из Интернет магазина Одежда). Как их удалить (при удалении возникает нижеуказанная ошибка)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в карту сайта добавить мною созданные инфоблоки [info] Информация и [other] Дополнительно и информацию из них?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Слайдер и Преимущества я не указал здесь подробно)

Есть предположение, что ошибка возникает из-за того, что карта сайта состоит не из моих инфоблоков (а из заданных по умолчанию, которые определялись при установке битрикса выбором шаблона интернет магазина).

2. Часть из старых инфоблоков (поставляемых со стандартным шаблоном Интернет магазином Одежда) я удалил и среди них были ссылающиеся на папку news. Возникло впечатление, что не все вхождения папки news (в предустановленный шаблон) удалились. Как найти их все и удалить их?

Answer (score 0):

1. В каждом инфоблоке есть информация нужно ли его индексировать.
2. В настройках карты сайта указывается из какого инфоблока нужно брать данные и какие - разделы или элементы.
3. Для удаления типа инфоблоков сначала нужно удалить все инфоблоки, а в них все элементы.