# Неправильно набран адрес, или такой страницы на сайте больше не существует для комплексного компонента Акции

Tags: php, веб-программирование, битрикс, компоненты, error404

Возникла такая же проблема, как и на [Ошибка: Неправильно набран адрес, или такой страницы на сайте больше не существует](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1505715/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83), только для комплексного компонента Акции.

Есть комплексный компонент Акции (файл `C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnosite.ru\actions\index.php`)

```html
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("title", "Акции для поисковиков");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Акции");
?>
    <!--
    <section>
        <div class="bread_crumbs_bl">
            <div class="standart_width">
                <ul class="bread_crumbs not_style">
                    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                        "bitrix:breadcrumb",
                        "",
                        Array(
                            "PATH" => "",
                            "SITE_ID" => "s1",
                            "START_FROM" => "0"
                        )
                    );?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    -->
    <section>
        <div class="gray_bg">
            <div class="standart_width">
                <div class="title">
                    <?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle(false);?>
                </div>
                <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                    "bitrix:news",
                    "actions",
                    Array(
                        "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => "Y",
                        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N",
                        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
                        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
                        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
                        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
                        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
                        "BROWSER_TITLE" => "-",
                        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
                        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
                        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
                        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
                        "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
                        "DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "j F Y",
                        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
                        "DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
                        "DETAIL_FIELD_CODE" => array("",""),
                        "DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "Y",
                        "DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE" => "",
                        "DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE" => "Страница",
                        "DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE" => array("",""),
                        "DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL" => "N",
                        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
                        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
                        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
                        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
                        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
                        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
                        "FILE_404" => "",
                        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
                        "IBLOCK_ID" => "7",
                        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "info",
                        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
                        "LIST_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "j F Y",
                        "LIST_FIELD_CODE" => array("",""),
                        "LIST_PROPERTY_CODE" => array("",""),
                        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
                        "META_DESCRIPTION" => "-",
                        "META_KEYWORDS" => "-",
                        "NEWS_COUNT" => "6",
                        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
                        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
                        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
                        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
                        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
                        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
                        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Акции",
                        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
                        "SEF_FOLDER" => "/actions/",
                        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
                        "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => Array("detail"=>"#ELEMENT_CODE#/","news"=>"","section"=>""),
                        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
                        "SET_STATUS_404" => "Y",
                        "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
                        "SHOW_404" => "Y",
                        "SORT_BY1" => "ID",
                        "SORT_BY2" => "ID",
                        "SORT_ORDER1" => "ASC",
                        "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
                        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
                        "USE_CATEGORIES" => "N",
                        "USE_FILTER" => "N",
                        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => "N",
                        "USE_RATING" => "N",
                        "USE_REVIEW" => "N",
                        "USE_RSS" => "N",
                        "USE_SEARCH" => "N",
                        "USE_SHARE" => "N"
                    )
                );?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    

<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Комплексный компонент Акции имеет следующие параметры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть также код списка Акций (файл `C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnosite.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news\actions\bitrix\news.list\.default\template.php`) из раздела Акций

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<div class="action_list">

<?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
    <?
    $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
    $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
    ?>
    <a class="action_el" href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>" id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arItem['ID']);?>">
        <span class="action_el_img"><img src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]['SRC']?>" alt="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]['ALT']?>"/></span>
        <span class="action_el_cont"><?=$arItem["NAME"]?></span>
    </a>

<?endforeach;?>

</div>
```

и код вызова детальной акции (файл `C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnosite.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news\actions\detail.php`)

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<?$ElementID = $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.detail",
    "",
    Array(
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => $arParams["DISPLAY_DATE"],
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => $arParams["DISPLAY_NAME"],
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"],
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT"],
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "FIELD_CODE" => $arParams["DETAIL_FIELD_CODE"],
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => $arParams["DETAIL_PROPERTY_CODE"],
        "DETAIL_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["detail"],
        "SECTION_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["section"],
        "META_KEYWORDS" => $arParams["META_KEYWORDS"],
        "META_DESCRIPTION" => $arParams["META_DESCRIPTION"],
        "BROWSER_TITLE" => $arParams["BROWSER_TITLE"],
        "SET_CANONICAL_URL" => $arParams["DETAIL_SET_CANONICAL_URL"],
        "DISPLAY_PANEL" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PANEL"],
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => $arParams["SET_LAST_MODIFIED"],
        "SET_TITLE" => $arParams["SET_TITLE"],
        "MESSAGE_404" => $arParams["MESSAGE_404"],
        "SET_STATUS_404" => $arParams["SET_STATUS_404"],
        "SHOW_404" => $arParams["SHOW_404"],
        "FILE_404" => $arParams["FILE_404"],
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => $arParams["INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN"],
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => $arParams["ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN"],
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => $arParams["DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT"],
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
        "USE_PERMISSIONS" => $arParams["USE_PERMISSIONS"],
        "GROUP_PERMISSIONS" => $arParams["GROUP_PERMISSIONS"],
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => $arParams["DETAIL_DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"],
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => $arParams["DETAIL_DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"],
        "PAGER_TITLE" => $arParams["DETAIL_PAGER_TITLE"],
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => $arParams["DETAIL_PAGER_TEMPLATE"],
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => $arParams["DETAIL_PAGER_SHOW_ALL"],
        "CHECK_DATES" => $arParams["CHECK_DATES"],
        "ELEMENT_ID" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["ELEMENT_ID"],
        "ELEMENT_CODE" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["ELEMENT_CODE"],
        "SECTION_ID" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_ID"],
        "SECTION_CODE" => $arResult["VARIABLES"]["SECTION_CODE"],
        "IBLOCK_URL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["news"],
        "USE_SHARE" => $arParams["USE_SHARE"],
        "SHARE_HIDE" => $arParams["SHARE_HIDE"],
        "SHARE_TEMPLATE" => $arParams["SHARE_TEMPLATE"],
        "SHARE_HANDLERS" => $arParams["SHARE_HANDLERS"],
        "SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_LOGIN" => $arParams["SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_LOGIN"],
        "SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_KEY" => $arParams["SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_KEY"],
        "ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN" => (isset($arParams["ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN"]) ? $arParams["ADD_ELEMENT_CHAIN"] : ''),
        'STRICT_SECTION_CHECK' => (isset($arParams['STRICT_SECTION_CHECK']) ? $arParams['STRICT_SECTION_CHECK'] : ''),
    ),
    $component
);?>
<p><a href="<?=$arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["news"]?>"><?=GetMessage("T_NEWS_DETAIL_BACK")?></a></p>
<?if($arParams["USE_RATING"]=="Y" && $ElementID):?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:iblock.vote",
    "",
    Array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "ELEMENT_ID" => $ElementID,
        "MAX_VOTE" => $arParams["MAX_VOTE"],
        "VOTE_NAMES" => $arParams["VOTE_NAMES"],
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
    ),
    $component
);?>
<?endif?>
<?if($arParams["USE_CATEGORIES"]=="Y" && $ElementID):
    global $arCategoryFilter;
    $obCache = new CPHPCache;
    $strCacheID = $componentPath.LANG.$arParams["IBLOCK_ID"].$ElementID.$arParams["CATEGORY_CODE"];
    if(($tzOffset = CTimeZone::GetOffset()) <> 0)
        $strCacheID .= "_".$tzOffset;
    if($arParams["CACHE_TYPE"] == "N" || $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"] == "A" && COption::GetOptionString("main", "component_cache_on", "Y") == "N")
        $CACHE_TIME = 0;
    else
        $CACHE_TIME = $arParams["CACHE_TIME"];
    if($obCache->StartDataCache($CACHE_TIME, $strCacheID, $componentPath))
    {
        $rsProperties = CIBlockElement::GetProperty($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], $ElementID, "sort", "asc", array("ACTIVE"=>"Y","CODE"=>$arParams["CATEGORY_CODE"]));
        $arCategoryFilter = array();
        while($arProperty = $rsProperties->Fetch())
        {
            if(is_array($arProperty["VALUE"]) && count($arProperty["VALUE"])>0)
            {
                foreach($arProperty["VALUE"] as $value)
                    $arCategoryFilter[$value]=true;
            }
            elseif(!is_array($arProperty["VALUE"]) && $arProperty["VALUE"] <> '')
                $arCategoryFilter[$arProperty["VALUE"]]=true;
        }
        $obCache->EndDataCache($arCategoryFilter);
    }
    else
    {
        $arCategoryFilter = $obCache->GetVars();
    }
    if(count($arCategoryFilter)>0):
        $arCategoryFilter = array(
            "PROPERTY_".$arParams["CATEGORY_CODE"] => array_keys($arCategoryFilter),
            "!"."ID" => $ElementID,
        );
        ?>
        <hr /><h3><?=GetMessage("CATEGORIES")?></h3>
        <?foreach($arParams["CATEGORY_IBLOCK"] as $iblock_id):?>
            <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
                "bitrix:news.list",
                $arParams["CATEGORY_THEME_".$iblock_id],
                Array(
                    "IBLOCK_ID" => $iblock_id,
                    "NEWS_COUNT" => $arParams["CATEGORY_ITEMS_COUNT"],
                    "SET_TITLE" => "N",
                    "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
                    "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
                    "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
                    "CACHE_GROUPS" => $arParams["CACHE_GROUPS"],
                    "FILTER_NAME" => "arCategoryFilter",
                    "CACHE_FILTER" => "Y",
                    "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
                    "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "N",
                ),
                $component
            );?>
        <?endforeach?>
    <?endif?>
<?endif?>
<?if($arParams["USE_REVIEW"]=="Y" && IsModuleInstalled("forum") && $ElementID):?>
<hr />
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:forum.topic.reviews",
    "",
    Array(
        "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
        "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
        "MESSAGES_PER_PAGE" => $arParams["MESSAGES_PER_PAGE"],
        "USE_CAPTCHA" => $arParams["USE_CAPTCHA"],
        "PATH_TO_SMILE" => $arParams["PATH_TO_SMILE"],
        "FORUM_ID" => $arParams["FORUM_ID"],
        "URL_TEMPLATES_READ" => $arParams["URL_TEMPLATES_READ"],
        "SHOW_LINK_TO_FORUM" => $arParams["SHOW_LINK_TO_FORUM"],
        "DATE_TIME_FORMAT" => $arParams["DETAIL_ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT"],
        "ELEMENT_ID" => $ElementID,
        "AJAX_POST" => $arParams["REVIEW_AJAX_POST"],
        "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "URL_TEMPLATES_DETAIL" => $arResult["FOLDER"].$arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["detail"],
    ),
    $component
);?>
<?endif?>
```

Файл `C:\OpenServer\domains\mytechnosite.ru\local\templates\main\components\bitrix\news\actions\bitrix\news.detail\.default\template.php` (шаблон детальной акции)

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>
<div class="news-detail">
    <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"])):?>
        <img
            class="detail_picture"
            border="0"
            src="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>"
            width="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["WIDTH"]?>"
            height="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["HEIGHT"]?>"
            alt="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["ALT"]?>"
            title="<?=$arResult["DETAIL_PICTURE"]["TITLE"]?>"
            />
    <?endif?>
    <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_DATE"]!="N" && $arResult["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]):?>
        <span class="news-date-time"><?=$arResult["DISPLAY_ACTIVE_FROM"]?></span>
    <?endif;?>
    <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_NAME"]!="N" && $arResult["NAME"]):?>
        <h3><?=$arResult["NAME"]?></h3>
    <?endif;?>
    <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT"]!="N" && $arResult["FIELDS"]["PREVIEW_TEXT"]):?>
        <p><?=$arResult["FIELDS"]["PREVIEW_TEXT"];unset($arResult["FIELDS"]["PREVIEW_TEXT"]);?></p>
    <?endif;?>
    <?if($arResult["NAV_RESULT"]):?>
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"]):?><?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?><br /><?endif;?>
        <?echo $arResult["NAV_TEXT"];?>
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"]):?><br /><?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?><?endif;?>
    <?elseif($arResult["DETAIL_TEXT"] <> ''):?>
        <?echo $arResult["DETAIL_TEXT"];?>
    <?else:?>
        <?echo $arResult["PREVIEW_TEXT"];?>
    <?endif?>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <br />
    <?foreach($arResult["FIELDS"] as $code=>$value):
        if ('PREVIEW_PICTURE' == $code || 'DETAIL_PICTURE' == $code)
        {
            ?><?=GetMessage("IBLOCK_FIELD_".$code)?>:&nbsp;<?
            if (!empty($value) && is_array($value))
            {
                ?><img border="0" src="<?=$value["SRC"]?>" width="<?=$value["WIDTH"]?>" height="<?=$value["HEIGHT"]?>"><?
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ?><?=GetMessage("IBLOCK_FIELD_".$code)?>:&nbsp;<?=$value;?><?
        }
        ?><br />
    <?endforeach;
    foreach($arResult["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $pid=>$arProperty):?>

        <?=$arProperty["NAME"]?>:&nbsp;
        <?if(is_array($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"])):?>
            <?=implode("&nbsp;/&nbsp;", $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]);?>
        <?else:?>
            <?=$arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"];?>
        <?endif?>
        <br />
    <?endforeach;
    if(array_key_exists("USE_SHARE", $arParams) && $arParams["USE_SHARE"] == "Y")
    {
        ?>
        <div class="news-detail-share">
            <noindex>
            <?
            $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:main.share", "", array(
                    "HANDLERS" => $arParams["SHARE_HANDLERS"],
                    "PAGE_URL" => $arResult["~DETAIL_PAGE_URL"],
                    "PAGE_TITLE" => $arResult["~NAME"],
                    "SHORTEN_URL_LOGIN" => $arParams["SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_LOGIN"],
                    "SHORTEN_URL_KEY" => $arParams["SHARE_SHORTEN_URL_KEY"],
                    "HIDE" => $arParams["SHARE_HIDE"],
                ),
                $component,
                array("HIDE_ICONS" => "Y")
            );
            ?>
            </noindex>
        </div>
        <?
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Но в результате при отображении детальной акции выдает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чем ошибка.

P.S. Файл `.htaccess` имеет вид

```html
Options -Indexes 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

<IfModule mod_php.c>
  php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
  php_flag session.use_trans_sid off
  php_value max_input_vars 10000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2} [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF] [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2} [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3} [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/virtual_file_system.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/virtual_file_system.php [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
  RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_dir.c>
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 3 day"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 day"  
</IfModule>
```

Файл `urlrewrite.php` имеет вид

```html
<?php
$arUrlRewrite=array (
  2 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/online/([\\.\\-0-9a-zA-Z]+)(/?)([^/]*)#',
    'RULE' => 'alias=$1',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/desktop_app/router.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/video([\\.\\-0-9a-zA-Z]+)(/?)([^/]*)#',
    'RULE' => 'alias=$1&videoconf',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/desktop_app/router.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^\\/?\\/mobileapp/jn\\/(.*)\\/.*#',
    'RULE' => 'componentName=$1',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/mobileapp/jn.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/bitrix/services/ymarket/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => '',
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/ymarket/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/online/(/?)([^/]*)#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/desktop_app/router.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  0 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/stssync/calendar/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:stssync.server',
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/stssync/calendar/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/personal/order/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:sale.personal.order',
    'PATH' => '/personal/order/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/personal/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:sale.personal.section',
    'PATH' => '/personal/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/store/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog.store',
    'PATH' => '/store/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/rest/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/rest/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/news/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/news/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
);
```

P.S. (2)

1. Если проблема в urlrewrite.php, то непонятно как аналогично

```html
  12 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/news/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/news/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  )
```

задать такой же блок для `actions` (с каким `id`) (для `news` это 12)?

2. И можно ли в `.htaccess` удалить строку (ничего ли не испорчу)

   RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]?

(если конечно она порождает мою проблему)

Comment: За что минусуете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
  13 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/actions/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/actions/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  )
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я бы посоветовал использовать не ```'ID' => 'bitrix:news'```, а ```'ID' => ''```, в противном случае это правило может вдруг исчезнуть при правке инфоблоков.